# Outlook Add-in: It's staying on add-in list, but how can I stop the delays when reopening the calendar

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, addin-express

We have a Outlook add-in, that is written in C#, that is working fine, and opens in the calendar view.
The add-in is set to "Load at Startup".
When someone is using another screen and then selects the calendar button, there is a significant delay and Outlook shows as "Not Responding".

I would like to keep the add-in loaded so that no delay is necessary.

Thanks for any help.

P.S. we are using .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: So if you pause the process in the debugger, what do you see on the call stack?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, I found that on the first load of the calendar screen it runs the initialisation of the main form of the add-in. After that, if I navigate to another screen (e.g. the Mail screen) and then navigate back to the calendar screen, sometimes it initialises again, and sometimes it just fires an event, which would suggest that, at least sometimes, it doesn't unload. The time delay is a rest call to one of our webservices, which is only called on initialisation of the add-in.

Comment: Do not do any synchronous network calls in your addin on the main thread - that's the easiest way to have your addin disabled by Outlook.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, thanks for the reply. In the end I used a static property to hold the results of the webserver call, and it only loads them on the first access of the calendar.

Comment: don't do it. It is so easy in C# to use a `Task` to perform any call asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code it is almost impossible to say the reason why users may experience any delays. I'd suggest looking at the [Explorer.BeforeFolderSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.beforefolderswitch), [Explorer.FolderSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.folderswitch) and [Explorer.SelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selectionchange) event handlers in the code of your add-in. All of them are fired when a calendar is opened in Outlook.

To understand better what is going on in the add-in and could cause the delay I'd suggest adding any logging mechanisms to the code. You may consider using the [log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/) which is a tool to help the programmer output log statements to a variety of output targets. In case of problems with an application, it is helpful to enable logging so that the problem can be located. With `log4net` it is possible to enable logging at runtime without modifying the application binary. The log4net package is designed so that log statements can remain in shipped code without incurring a high performance cost. It follows that the speed of logging (or rather not logging) is crucial.

When you get logs from a problematic machine you may analyze them and find a possible cause.